# Modern ExtJS 6 6.2 isValid() is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs-form

Can I use the **`isValid()`** method in the **modern version 6.2 EXTJS** as I use it in the classic version?

In the classic version it works, but in the modern version there is error:

> **form.isValid() is not a function**

**FeedForm.js**

```
Ext.define('FeedViewer.view.main.FeedForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'feedform',

    requires: [
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.Toolbar'
    ],

    title: 'New RSS Feed',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label: 'Select a new feed',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            allowBlank: false,
            name: 'feedUrl',
            options: [{
                value: 'http://rssfeeds.usatoday.com/usatoday-NewsTopStories',
                text: 'USA Today Top Stories'
            }, {
                value: 'http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news',
                text: 'ESPN Top News'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            reference: 'savebutton',
            action: 'save',
            ui: 'action',
            text: 'Add'
        }]
    }]
});
```

**MainController.js**

```
var form = me.dialog.down('form');

if (form.isValid()) {

}
```

Comment: I would console.log(form) perhaps it is `me.dialog.down('form');` that does not work as expected

Comment: I used: var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('feedform')[0];   record = form.getRecord(),    //It's work
  values = form.getValues(), //It's work// form.isValid()  - It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `modern` toolkit, you have to use **`me.dialog.down('formpanel')`** instead of `me.dialog.down('form')`

**References:-**

**1.** [`xtype: 'form'`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html) in `classic` toolkit.

**2.** [`xtype: 'formpanel'`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.form.Panel.html) in `modern` toolkit.

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: me.dialog.down('formpanel') isn't work; I used: `var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('feedform')[0]; record = form.getRecord()`, -It's work `values = form.getValues()`, - It's work// `form.isValid()` - It doesn't work

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jk8)

Comment: Version 6.6 modern - work great; but version 6.2 modern doesn't work

Comment: So you can use [`validators`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-validators) and it's [`isValid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.Model.html#method-isValid) method.

Comment: In version classic I used: isValid; in modern: validators; on localhost http://localhost:1841/ everything is ok; but on server doesn't work, because  I see red triangle in grid(local storage doesn't work); When I delete validators everything is ok, but I don't have validators in modern version

Comment: Post [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have tried and what problem you are facing.